# Orthogonal arrays

Tags: experiment-design, latin-square, orthogonal

This is from a note I found 
[image]

I have one question, could t=3?

Comment: Isn't that the case for the array you show? Within each $N\times 3$ subarray, each of the tuples appears equally often. A bunch of small cases with $t=3$ are discussed [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/preprints/oa3.pdf). A quick search turns up several papers discussing methods for construction of arrays of strength 3.

Comment: @Glen_b the note actually says that t cannot be 3, t can only be 2. I think it might relate to  the definition of "t -tuple", is it  actually tuples appear in the row or all possibile tuples?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking me there. However, it's definitely the case that you can get asymmetric orthogonal arrays of strength three. [Here's](http://www.isid.ac.in/~statmath/2016/isid201602.pdf) one of the papers that offer constructions. Section 4.7 of the book *Fractional Factorial plans* by Dey and Mukherjee discusses them as well. In general Hadamard matrices are used to construct them.

Comment: It's not possible to resolve a statement we have no context for; perhaps there some condition you're failing to mention. As your question stands the answer is "Yes". The only reason that's not currently posted as an answer is "yes" is a bit brief... and I fear that as soon as I answer it you'll change the question.